# How to connect dashDB (on Bluemix) with Object Storage (on Bluemix)?

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb, object-storage

I am using Public Bluemix. I have provisioned a dashDB service instance using my IBM ID in Bluemix. I have also provisioned a Object Storage service. I would like to load files from Object Storage into dashDB.

When I try to define a load job in dashDB to get a file from Object Storage, I face a problem.

dashDB allows me to choose either Amazon S3 or Swift Object Store as the data source. I chose "Swift" and then provided the following Bluemix Object Store service credentials.

1. Public authentication endpoint : https://identity.open.softlayer.com
2. User name: as found in my my Bluemix Object Store credentials 'username'
3. API access key: as found in my my Bluemix Object Store credentials 'password'

Then, I clicked "Browse swift files", expecting to see the files which exist in my Bluemix Object Store's container. But, it shows me just a blank folder and no files.

I need to understand the method to connect Bluemix dashDB to Bluemix Object Store. Please help.

Comment: Hi Aditya, so did you find a solution for connecting dashDB on BlueMix with whatever storage solution also on BlueMix?

Comment: Hello, Can someone officially confirm this? That one can import data from Amazon S3 or Softlayer object storage to Bluemix Dash DB, but cannot do so from Bluemix Object Storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having trouble getting this to work too.

At first, I found an answer on dWAnswers that said this may not be supported.

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/166630/dataworks-integration-between-object-storage-and-d.html

**Edit:**

The Bluemix support team got back to me with the following message:

> For loading from Swift, Bluemix Object Storage is not supported 
>   and only object storage on SoftLayer is supported at this time.
>
> Thanks.